# How to prove the Hamilton formula for quaternions

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions

$i^{2}=j^{2}=k^{2}=ijk=-1$

What kind of entities $i$, $j$ and $k$ are? and how to prove the aforementioned equation?

Comment: $i$, $j$ and $k$ are *quaternions*.

Answer (score 2):

That equation is close to a definition of quaternions and therefore not much to prove.

The entities $i$, $j$, $k$ are different imaginary units. But if you refer to representations of the quaternions they can be different things depending on what representation you use. One well-known representation can be constructed using the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) 
$$
i := -\imath \sigma_x = \begin{pmatrix}0&-\imath\\ -\imath&0\end{pmatrix},
\quad
j := -\imath \sigma_x = \begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},
\quad
k := -\imath \sigma_x = \begin{pmatrix}-\imath&0\\0&\imath\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $\imath$ is the ordinary imaginary unit.

Comment: In addition, to form a complete set, you need to add $1$. In the above representation, $1$ is the $2\times2$ identity matrix.

Comment: The trouble is, $i^2=-1$ etc., unlike your Pauli matrices.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown. I realized that I had posted an incorrect answer when I was trying to sleep. I fixed it now.

Comment: @DietrichBurde. Fixed.